# Splunk: Split extracted field after specific position

Tags: splunk

I extracted a filed which contains phone numbers. The extracted field is named `phoneNumbers`. I now want to split this field after the fourth number to get the area code.
How could I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `substr` function.

```
... | eval areaCode = substr(phoneNumbers, 1, 3)
```

Comment: The only amendment is that for my task I had to use `eval areaCode = substr(phoneNumbers, 1, 4)` instead of `eval areaCode = substr(phoneNumbers, 1, 3)` to get the first four characters of `phoneNumbers`.